# Subfloor section replacement, leveling within room

Tags: subfloor

I might replace a section of subfloor in my bathroom, the issue is the floor has two layers of glued vinyl and I'm not ripping it all up. How can I raise the section I replace up so the LVP I add will go smoothly over it? Are two layers of glued down vinyl tile OK?

Comment: If the subfloor and vinyl tiles in good condition and level, then they can be left usually.  Don't say the area you plan on removing and replacing, but there self levelling products to level out a floor.  Usually recommended to remove all old flooring, but quite a few don't if it is in good condition(50/60 years and floor is raise 3 inches).

Comment: Are you asking if it's "ok" to have more than one layer of vinyl, or how to build up a section of floor to the level of the rest with two layers? Pictures may help, but I think it's going to be best to remove the old flooring first and then put new down.

Comment: The later, need to build it up. I don't want to remove large sections of asbestos.